# undefined reference to `WinMain@16' mingw converting to DLL

Tags: c, visual-studio

I am trying to convert the given C code to DLL file I tried to compile the given code but it doesn't work it gives me an error

```
.\sample.cpp:16:66: warning: passing NULL to non-pointer argument 5 of 'void* CreateThread(LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, DWORD, LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE, PVOID, DWORD, PDWORD)' [-Wconversion-null]
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xb0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have already tried looking up the answers available online, along with looking at the syntax which seems to be okay.

My Code

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
DWORD WINAPI MessageBoxThread(LPVOID lpParam) {
  MessageBox(NULL, "Hello world!", "Hello World!", NULL);
  return 0;
}

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
                      DWORD ul_reason_for_call,
                      LPVOID lpReserved) {
  switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      CreateThread(NULL, NULL, MessageBoxThread, NULL, NULL, NULL);
      break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: In visual studio, check the properties and check that the 'system' property is set to a DLL and not Windows.  Your code appears to be correct, however the error suggest that you are compiling for a windows application.

Comment: @thurizas I don't think I can find it in VS Code

Comment: VS Code is a text editor. Visual Studio is an IDE. You will not find the option in VS Code. But you can compile a dll using mingw. Still you should be using Visual Studio IDE for this.

Comment: Show how you are invoking the compiler. Probably you are telling it to build a .exe instead of a .dll

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 community edition, version 15.8.1 for reference.  I created a simple DLL project (using File | New | Project) and removed all files except `dllmain.cpp` I had to modify the project properties to disable the use of precompiled headers.  The code in `dllmain.cpp` is:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN   
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
DWORD WINAPI MessageBoxThread(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Hello World", "Hello World", MB_YESNO);
    return 0;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule, DWORD  dwReason, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    switch (dwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            DWORD   dwTID;
            CreateThread(nullptr, 0, MessageBoxThread, nullptr, 0, &dwTID);
            break;
        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

I've made a few modifications from your code,

1. I passed `MB_YESNO` as the final argument to MessageBox instead of a null pointer.  This will give your message box YES and NO buttons, and this matches the type expected (uint) for the fourth parameter.
2. I used MessageBoxA to force ASCII argument instead of MessageBox, which is a typedef that resolves to MessageBoxW.  This effects the type of strings that is expected, and is based on if you are using Unicode or not.
3. I passed a value of zero for the second argument (dwStackSize) and the fifth argument (dwCreationFlags) of `CreateThread` instead of NULL. Both of these arguments have type DWORD.   Notice that this fixes the first line of your error message ".\sample.cpp:16:66: warning: passing NULL to non-pointer argument 5"
4. I declared a variable `dwTID` and pass a pointer to it as the sixth argument of `CreateThread`.
5. I added a break statement to the first case.  This should not have any consequence in the code.  I just think it is a good idea.

The above code compiles without warnings or errors.  Thus I believe that your code should also compile as well.  Thus I strongly suspect that the errors you are seeing are due to the compiler and linker flags you are using.  The command lines that are being used are

for compilation:

```
/JMC /permissive- /GS /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /ZI /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "TESTDLL_EXPORTS" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_USRDLL" /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /Gd /Oy- /MDd /FC /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\testDll.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

for linking:

```
/OUT:"D:\GNUHome\Projects\testDll\Debug\testDll.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:\GNUHome\Projects\testDll\Debug\testDll.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib"/IMPLIB:"D:\GNUHome\Projects\testDll\Debug\testDll.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"D:\GNUHome\Projects\testDll\Debug\testDll.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\testDll.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Because you are not using native Microsoft toos (CL and LINK), you are going to need to find or prepare a mapping between the tool chain you are using (which you did not mention, but it appears to be mingw from the error messages) and Microsoft's tool chain.

If'n I had to guess, I would suspect that the issue is due to the `/DLL` flag in the linking command line.  You might have to use something line `-shared` with mingw.  However this is just a guess.